# Excel VBA checking and comparing dates between workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I've got an excel script that that checks and compare dates between cells in different workbooks.

- I've got four workbooks, `wbk`, `wbkA`, `wbkB`, `wbkC`, and `wbkD`.
- Date in last cell in `Column A` of `wbk` is used as `reference date`
- Date in Cell `A9` of the rest of the workbooks is checked against `reference date` to check that they are one day after reference date
- results are written to a `log file`
- The script should write all results to a log (whether date is ok or not) and should only continue when all dates are ok. Ohterwise it should write to the log file which dates are not ok and exit sub.

  - If possible I would like to be call comparebooks from other modules instead

My problem:

- Date checks work individually but I'm having trouble getting the script to check for multiple dates without running into errors
- I cannot get it to work together with the writing to the log

Script to check compare dates

```
Sub comparebooks()

    Dim dateX As Date
    Dim dateA As Date
    Dim dateB As Date
    Dim dateC As Date
    Dim dateD As Date

sFilename = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Logs.txt"
sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Source\"
sFile = Dir(sPath & "2G Voice*.xlsx")
sFile1 = Dir(sPath & "2G Data*.xlsx")
sFile2 = Dir(sPath & "3G*.xlsx")
sFile3 = Dir(sPath & "4G*.xlsx")


'reference date file 4G
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\2G.xlsx")
    Set varSheet = wbk.Worksheets("2G Voice")
    dateX = wbk.Worksheets("2G Voice").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)


'file dates to check
    Set wbkA = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFile)
    Set varSheetA = wbkA.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    dateA = wbkA.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A9")

    Set wbkB = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFile1)
    Set varSheetB = wbkB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    dateB = wbkB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A9")

    Set wbkC = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFile2)
    Set varSheetC = wbkC.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    dateC = wbkC.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A9")

    Set wbkD = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFile3)
    Set varSheetD = wbkD.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    dateD = wbkD.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A9")


    'check 4g date
    If dateA = DateAdd("d", 1, dateX) Then
    Debug.Print dateA & " 2G Voice is OK"

    If dateB = DateAdd("d", 1, dateX) Then
    Debug.Print dateB & " 2G Data is OK"

    If dateC = DateAdd("d", 1, dateX) Then
    Debug.Print dateC & " 3G CS_PS is OK"

    If dateD = DateAdd("d", 1, dateX) Then
    Debug.Print dateD & " 4G Data is OK"

Else
    Debug.Print "Date is not OK"

End If

    Exit Sub

    End If


End Sub
```

Logbook script

```
 ' Archive file at certain size
    If FileLen(sFilename) > 20000 Then
        FileCopy sFilename _
            , Replace(sFilename, ".txt", Format(Now, "ddmmyyyy hhmmss.txt"))
        Kill sFilename
    End If

    ' Open the file to write
    Dim filenumber As Variant
    filenumber = FreeFile
    Open sFilename For Append As #filenumber

    Print #filenumber, CStr(Now) & ", " & "Missing source file: " & strType & " is missing " & chknum - i & " file(s)"

    Close #filenumber

End If
```

Can someone please assist?

Comment: Is there such syntax of "IFs" proper? Even If you write IFs in one-line, the last ELSE belongs to  "If dateD = DateAdd("d", 1, dateX) Then". I would use select case or just multpily booleans. And one more thing when reading Range("A9"): you can acces cells values without opening workbooks.

Comment: @RafałB. noted. thanks.